# Wrong version of dependence gem when run test for my gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rubygems

I have been developing gem.
For test my gem I use ActiveRecord.
When I run test I get some error because my gem doesn't support version 5.0 of ActiveRecord.

But in my gemspec I have:

```
spec.add_development_dependency 'activerecord', '~> 4.2'
```

Also I tried to user Gemfile.local but it didn't get positive result.

What a right way for set particular version for a gem?

Comment: Try this `spec.add_development_dependency "activerecord", "~> 4.0.0"` Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18543155/testing-a-gem-that-uses-activerecord-models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out problem was in my test_helper file:

```
begin
  require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../../../../config/environment'
rescue LoadError
  require 'rubygems'
  gem 'activerecord'
  gem 'actionpack'
  require 'active_record'
 end
```

When I setted  explicit  version for gem everything has worked fine:

```
gem 'activerecord', "4.2.7.1"
gem 'actionpack', "4.2.7.1"
```