# Testing a gem that uses ActiveRecord models using Postgres + Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rspec, rubygems

I'm trying to test some models in a gem using Rspec and Postgres. Currently trying to do this by running a rake task in the spec_helper.rb file that will establish the pg database connection for the duration of my Rspec tests.

I've scanned other questions (my approach is largely based on these two questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18543155/testing-a-gem-that-uses-activerecord-models),
[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398262/setup-rspec-to-test-a-gem-not-rails)) and haven't discovered a good solution.

I'm not using the sqlite in-memory db feature due to the way our code is written.

Custom spec_helper looks like this:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  load "support/schema.rb"
  load File.expand_path("../../../lib/tasks/database.rake", __FILE__)
  require File.dirname(__FILE__) + 'support/models.rb'
  Rake::Task['database'].invoke
```

However when I run rspec it tells me that there is no connection pool:

```
active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:570:in
`retrieve_connection': No connection pool for ActiveRecord::Base
(ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished)
```

Does anyone have any advice or insight on this issue? It would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### You should establish database connection:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(adapter: 'postgresql', 
  encoding: 'unicode', database: '<db_name>', username: '<user>')
```

This should run before any others database interactions (including loading `schema.rb`)

Comment: here is my database task in rake:                                                                `desc "Establishes postgresql connection"`
`task :database do`
`  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(`
`        adapter:    'postgresql',`
`        host:       'tmp',`
`        database:   'user',`
`        username:   'user',`
`        password:   '',`
`        port:       5432,`
`      )`
`    end`

Comment: I think you should `load "support/schema.rb"` after establishing database connection

Comment: this solved the error - there are still a few issues with connecting to the db, but it seems the connection had to be established before loading the files. thanks!